# Narrowing down records in repeat region with check-boxes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Let me start by saying i'm a bit of a newbie to php & Mysql.

I am making a site with multiple holyday houses the are stored in a database I'm showing them on a page in a repeatable region (which is a include), the results are also paginated.

(at this moment there are only five entry's to test but there will be a few hundred when i'm ready)

What i'm trying to achieve is that a visitor can narrow down the shown results with a group of check boxes(also an include) that represent variable options like state, swimming pool, WiFi etc.

The result of checking the boxes should narrow down the amount of result in the repeatable region.

I've been searching for day's now and i'm really stuck!
Could someone have a look at my code and show me in the right direction or hint me to a way of doing what i want to achieve?

The code on the result page:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/vakantiewoningentest.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

$maxRows_Recordset1 = 4;
$pageNum_Recordset1 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'])) {
  $pageNum_Recordset1 = $_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'];
}
$startRow_Recordset1 = $pageNum_Recordset1 * $maxRows_Recordset1;

mysql_select_db($database_vakantiewoningentest, $vakantiewoningentest);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM vw_form_3 ORDER BY provincie ASC";
$query_limit_Recordset1 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_Recordset1, $startRow_Recordset1, $maxRows_Recordset1);
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset1, $vakantiewoningentest) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_Recordset1'])) {
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = $_GET['totalRows_Recordset1'];
} else {
  $all_Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1);
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($all_Recordset1);
}
$totalPages_Recordset1 = ceil($totalRows_Recordset1/$maxRows_Recordset1)-1;

$queryString_Recordset1 = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_Recordset1") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_Recordset1") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_Recordset1 = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_Recordset1 = sprintf("&totalRows_Recordset1=%d%s", $totalRows_Recordset1, $queryString_Recordset1);
?>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
       if (isset($_POST['interested']))
       {
           $strInterested = implode (",", $_post['interested']);
       }
       else   
       {
           $strInterested = "";
       }
       echo "intersted in: " . $strInterested;
       exit ();   
  }
?>
```

The check box group code:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"><table width="140" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="td-filter">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" height="15"><h1>Filter resultaten:</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" height="15"><hr /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Per provincie:</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="103" class="">Ancona</td>
    <td width="33"><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="Ancona">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ascoli Piceno</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="Ascoli Piceno">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fermo</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="Fermo">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Macerata</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="Macerata">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pesaro Urbino</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="Pesaro Urbino">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" height="15"><hr /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Op accomodatie:</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Agriturismo</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="agriturismo">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Vakantiewoning</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="Vakantiewoning">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Appartement</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="Appartement">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B&amp;B</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="B and B">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Camping</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="Camping">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" height="15"><hr /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Opties:</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zwembad</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="Zwembad">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wifi</td>
    <td><input name="interested[]" type="checkbox" id="interested[]" value="Wifi">
      <label for="interested[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="15"><hr /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="zoek!"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Where do i go wrong??
Let me know if you want to know more.
I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me out!

Comment: Note that, ID should be unique in HTML.

Comment: As far as i could find online was that if you want multiple check boxes processed, this was the way to do it...

Comment: That is correct for the name -> `name="interested[]"` but not for the id -> `id="interested[]"`, which should be unique, ie. `id="interested0"`/`id="interested1"`/etc

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of looking stupid, I'm just going to point out that there is no `WHERE` statement in your query and I don't see any sort of JavaScript changing the results on the client side.

If you're stuck, the first thing I'd do is fix the repeating IDs that Sean mentioned in his comment above. But the big thing is you need a `WHERE` statement that takes the posted HTML array of your checkboxes (still named `interested[]` just IDed differently) and do a `WHERE IN` against and `implode` of the variable.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you require you need to construct a dynamic query. I will use [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as it is easier to construct and mysql_ functions are deprecated. You can learn more about PDO in this [**Wiki**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

The following code uses some of your form. Note I have removed id as stated by lolka_bolka as these need to be unique.

```
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT * FROM vw_form_3  ";//Query stub
$params = array();//Array to hold parameters
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['provincie'])){
        $in ="";
        foreach($_POST['provincie'] as $c){
           if(!empty($c)){
                $in  .= "?,";//Add ? placeholder
                array_push($params,$c);//Add parameter to array
                }
            }
            $in = rtrim($in, ",");
            $sql .= $clause." `provincie` IN(";
            $sql .=$in.")";
            $clause = " AND ";//Change  to AND after 1st WHERE
    }
    if(isset($_POST['accomodatie'])){
        $in ="";
        foreach($_POST['accomodatie'] as $c){
            if(!empty($c)){
                $in  .= "?,";
                array_push($params,$c);
                }
            }
            $in = rtrim($in, ",");
            $sql .= $clause." `accomodatie` IN(";
            $sql .=$in.")";
            $clause = " AND ";//Change  to AND after 1st WHERE
    }
```

The next 3 lines are for testing and can be removed.

```
echo $sql;
echo "<br>";
print_r($params);
```

The query can now be executed using  "lazy" binding (using array in execute())

```
// Execute the query
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute($params);
}

?>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="#"><table width="140" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="td-filter">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" height="15"><h1>Filter resultaten:</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" height="15"><hr /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Per provincie:</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="103" class="">Ancona</td>
    <td width="33"><input name="provincie[]" type="checkbox" value="Ancona">
      <label for="provincie[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ascoli Piceno</td>
    <td><input name="provincie[]" type="checkbox"  value="Ascoli Piceno">
      <label for="provincie[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fermo</td>
    <td><input name="provincie[]" type="checkbox"  value="Fermo">
      <label for="provincie[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Macerata</td>
    <td><input name="provincie[]" type="checkbox"  value="Macerata">
      <label for="provincie[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pesaro Urbino</td>
    <td><input name="provincie[]" type="checkbox"  value="Pesaro Urbino">
      <label for="provincie[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" height="15"><hr /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Op accomodatie:</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Agriturismo</td>
    <td><input name="accomodatie[]" type="checkbox"  value="agriturismo">
      <label for="accomodatie[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Vakantiewoning</td>
    <td><input name="accomodatie[]" type="checkbox"  value="Vakantiewoning">
      <label for="accomodatie[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Appartement</td>
    <td><input name="accomodatie[]" type="checkbox"  value="Appartement">
      <label for="accomodatie[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B&amp;B</td>
    <td><input name="accomodatie[]" type="checkbox"  value="B and B">
      <label for="accomodatie[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Camping</td>
    <td><input name="accomodatie[]" type="checkbox"  value="Camping">
      <label for="accomodatie[]"></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="zoek!"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Typical result

```
SELECT * FROM vw_form_3 WHERE `provincie` IN(?,?) AND `accomodatie` IN(?,?)
array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "Ancona" [1]=> string(13) "Ascoli Piceno" [2]=> string(11) "agriturismo" [3]=> string(14) "Vakantiewoning" }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try this out first thing tomorrow morning, I'll let you know.